# Data Binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, c++-cx

I am having a problem with data binding in XAML.  I am just learning WPF, and after two days of research, I came up with this code:

C++/CX:

```
namespace App1
{    
    class buttonColor {

    public:
        buttonColor(Windows::UI::Color c) { foreground = c; }

        Windows::UI::Color get() { return foreground; }

        void set(Windows::UI::Color c) { foreground = c; }

    private:
        Windows::UI::Color foreground;
    };
}
```

I call it with this:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    buttonColor t(Windows::UI::Colors::Blue);
}
```

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="buttonColor" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DataContext="{StaticResource buttonColor}">

    <Button Content="Test" Foreground="{Binding Source=t}" />
</Grid>
```

This sort of works: it does change the foreground to a dull red, but I can't control the color change.  Does anyone know why this is not changing to the colors I tell it in my C++/CX code?

Update:

I posted my full code on GitHub here: https://github.com/user2509848/wpf/tree/master.  Right now, all I am getting is a linking error that `_foreColorProperty` cannot be found.  If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think anything like this can ever work in C++ because C++ lacks all the introspective features required for this kind of stuff. Unless, of course, this is a language that's not real C++ but just resembles it, in which case the question is not tagged correctly.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I am writing a Windows 8 app with XAML/C++, and the example apps do have Data Binding.  Otherwise, I would be struggling to learn C# now instead.  I suppose I can switch now...

Comment: Did you perhaps mean C++/CX which is a language that kinda-sorta looks like C++ but most definitely isn't C++?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Possibly; Visual Studio just calls it a Windows 8 C++ app, but it could be C++/CX.

Comment: What happens if for test purposes you expose an explicit public "TheColor" property in the buttonColor class and bind to it via Foreground="{Binding TheColor}"?

Comment: Microsoft likes to confuse people with their not-C++ languages they still somehow call C++. They have multiple.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen OK, I just looked it up, and I am definitely using C++/CX.

Comment: @JamesDevlin Do you mean add this too the C++ class: `Windows::UI::Color theColor = Windows::UI::Colors::Blue;` and change the XAML to this: `Binding Source=theColor`?  In this case, the text remains white as if I hadn't done anything.

Comment: @hosch250, for sure the answer has to do with the notifications issued in your 'buttonColor' class.  That much is clear.  But to do that in C++/CX?  You got me on that one.

Comment: @hosch250, also it looks like 't' will go out of scope.

Comment: @GarryVass My XAML code is in `MainPage.xaml`.  `t` is created in `MainPage.xaml.cpp`.  I don't think it is going out of scope because that is where I handle button clicks and everything else in `MainPage.xaml`.

Comment: @GarryVass I know a little C#.  If you post a C# answer, I may be able to solve it from there.

Comment: @hosch250, I can add a C# rendition for SOME of it, I'm not altogether sure how well it would port though.  It may have limited use because of that.  If you don't get a good answer in c++ you can ping me for a C# treatment if it will be of any use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's a common mistake to use a Color instead of a Brush.
- And also you should remove `Source=` or replace it with `Path=`

So instead of

```
<Button Content="Test" Foreground="{Binding t}" />
```

write:

```
<Button Content="Test"/>
    <Button.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding t}"/>
    </Button.Foreground>
</Button>
```

### Edited

The reason you can't see the color changes, is your property does not notify the XAML about the changes.

In Header:

```
public:
static property Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty^ ForeColorProperty
{
     Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty^ get()
     {
          return _foreColorProperty;
     }
}
public:
property Windows::UI::Color^ ForeColor
{
     Windows::UI::Color^ get()
     {
          return (Windows::UI::Color^)GetValue(ForeColorProperty);
     }
     void set(Windows::UI::Color^ value)
     {
          SetValue(ForeColorProperty, value);
     }
}
```

In CPP:

```
DependencyProperty^ MainPage::_foreColorProperty = DependencyProperty::Register(
    "ForeColor",
    GetTypeName<Windows::UI::Color>(),
    GetTypeName<MainPage>(),
    ref new PropertyMetadata(nullptr));
```

Then use `"{Binding ForeColor}"` to bind to this property.

### More info

`DataContext` value of each `FrameworkElement` is responsible for resolving the binding path. Which means in order to bind correctly you should first make sure `DataContext` has the correct value. `DataContext` always inherits its value from its parent which means if you set the `DataContext` of `MainPage` to something, `DataContext` of Button will be equal to it unless set explicitly.

e.g. When you say `<Button Foreground="{Binding t}">` you mean to set the foreground of Button to `Button.DataContext.t`

In this example `DataContext` of Button is supposed to be equal to the current instance of `MainPage` because we defined _foreColorProperty for this parent type: `GetTypeName<MainPage>()`

```
DependencyProperty^ MainPage::_foreColorProperty = DependencyProperty::Register(
    "ForeColor",
    GetTypeName<Windows::UI::Color>(),
--> GetTypeName<MainPage>(),
    ref new PropertyMetadata(nullptr));
```

But that's not enough, **You have to set it in the constructor of MainPage:**

```
DataContext = this;
```

If we need another class as the **ViewModel** for the `MainPage` we should create another class and add these properties to it (and change GetTypeName() too) and then

```
MyViewModelClass* vm = new MyViewModelClass();
DataContext = vm;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I got this to almost work, but `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` are not defined.  Do I need to define these myself?

Comment: The class containing a dependency property must derive from DependencyObject. and that will provide these functions.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for bothering, but which file is each part supposed to be in?  Is the "In Header:" part in` MainPage.xaml.h` inside this class: `public ref class MainPage sealed` and the "In CPP:" part in `MainPage.xaml.cpp`?  If so, I have a few errors, although the `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` errors are cleared up.

Comment: Yes that's how it should be. I also added some info to my answer

Comment: Perfect!!! It works now!  Only two problems: I needed to add `private: static Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty^ _foreColorProperty;` to Header and I needed to change the `GetTypeName<value>(),` lines to `value::typeid,`.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: sorry I don't know much of C++. you have to ask another question about that.